# Embed a framework without module in a Pod

Tags: swift, module, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm using a 3rd party library provided as a framework : Library.framework. Apparently, it can only be used in my `Swift` project via the Bridging Header by doing `#import <Library/Library.h>`. Which is fine in most cases.

However, I'm currently developing a Pod in which I want to use Library.framework. This means that I cannot rely on the Bridging Header.

I tried to link the Library.framework in my Pod target (see `General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries`) but then, once the Pod is installed in my app, Xcode says the Pod cannot compile because some files in Library are not found.

What would be the best strategy to adopt here ?

Comment: Did you try to edit your scheme ? In the build section you can choose the order your targets compile if you uncheck "parallelize build"

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that raises some more questions : what scheme and what is it supposed to do ?

Comment: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Build. Then uncheck "parallelize build" and you can reorder your targets

Comment: It does not change anything. The problem remains : files in my Pod's Library.framework are not found.

Comment: Maybe take a look at build phases. Check if your library appears in "Link Binary With Libraries" and "Embed Frameworks"

Comment: @aimak could you provide sample code so that we can check what's the issue exactly and which 3rd party library are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I made it.

The trick was to add the .h files in both `source_files` and `public_header_files` in the Pod.podspec.

Like this :

```
s.source_files = 'Library.framework/Headers/*.h'
s.public_header_files = 'Library.framework/Headers/*.h'
```

This way, all the header files appear in the `Pod-umbrella.h` and can now be used in my app.

Answer (score 1):

In your pod project I assume you have a file named [PodName].h, it will look similar to the file below.
You could try to add the header in this file.

```
//
//  PodName.h
//  PodName
//
//  Created by John Doe on 06.04.2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 John Doe Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for PodName.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double PodNameVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for PodName.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char PodNameVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <PodName/PublicHeader.h>

#import <Library/Library.h> // Add framework header here.
```